# Error while opening PDF

Tags: c#

I am getting "**Failed to load PDF document**" in Chrome and "**The file is damaged and could not be repaired**" in IE for few files.

The code is as below:

PDFSteramer:

```
if (pdf != null)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/PDF";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");

    pdf.Renderer.Render(pdf, Response.OutputStream);

    Response.Flush();
}
```

And in Render class:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(this._ParentDocument.Document.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{                                                 
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    fs.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer)))
    {                        
        Decoder decoder = new UuDecoder(stream, "");

        string data;

        while ((data = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            decoder.DecodeLine(data);
        }
    }
}
```

and in DecodeLine is as below:

```
public override bool DecodeLine(string line)
{
    try
    {                                                             
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line);
        //byte[] data = uuDecode(line);

        outStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);                  
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return false;
}
```

Below is what it throws in Firefox:

[image]

And on Adobe reader:

[image]

Comment: not sure you can read a pdf file as a text one (i.e. reading strings from it, instead of read it binary), but if this is correct, reading using ASCII encoding and then decoding it in UTF8 sounds bad. Why don't you simply return the binary file content you read?

Comment: any link for that? @GianPaolo

Comment: That should just be transmitted as binary, not as text. Not sure why you bother converting it to anything. Just set the ContentLength, read the pdf as bytes and and dump those bytes into the stream.

Comment: please share any link if you can @Nyerguds

Comment: I'd try with a an `outStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);` just after reading the buffer, and skip your following code

Comment: I am still getting that error @GianPaolo even after following your steps. may be something is wrong in PDF file itself?

Comment: you can test the file dragging it in chrome from the file system. next test: check the buffer you are writing out is equal to the file.

Comment: Do you use asp.net MVC? If not, which framework you use? Show us full code of the method of "PDFSteramer" you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

If your PDF is stored in a physical file, you don't need to use intermediary streams at all, just use the [TransmitFile method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy.aspx) which also has the benefit of not using .NET memory (in most cases):

```
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
   Response.TransmitFile(your pdf path);
```

Comment: actually it is not exact PDF file..its an SGML file from which we extract PDF file. still I can use this?

Comment: Do you have a whole physical PDFsomewhere? Or can you build one?

Comment: PDF is not stored anywhere. its an SGML file from which we take out some data line by line and we create PDF from it. does it make sense now?

Comment: Well, it probably means what you write out on the web is a broken/damaged PD. Try to write it out on a file and double click on it to check that.

Comment: i dont get your last line. "Try to write it out on a file and double click on it to check that."

Comment: instead of outputing it on the the web stream, output it on a real file (FileStream)

Comment: pdf files work but image files dont work :(

Comment: @telatkaya - MIME type depends on file extension, consult this for extension <=> MIME type correspondance:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working with the META data in the SGML, is it possible to render it directly as a PDF? It is so easy to convert HTML directly to PDF instead of trying to pull random data and hoping that it still works.  Can you show us whats in the SGML file? Might help everyone get into your mindset of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with images, and after a while I got it working by changing the encoding (in your case `Encoding.UTF8`) to ASCII (`Encoding.ASCII`). Try it out. I do not guarantee success, but it is definitely worth a try.

Another reason it could help is that you apparently use two different encodings anyway, in the Render class you wrote `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer)` while later using the UTF-8 encoding.